# How to listen to Keypresses in Elisp?

Tags: emacs

I want to make a function that counts keyboard presses. Is there any function or hook that would let me listen to the input without modifying it?

I've tried read-event and read-char, set some variable that read input, incremented the number of keyboard presses and then inserted it into the file, but it failed. It prevents you from using any keystrokes, it also interprets keys like Backspace as a "/?", thus making it impossible to delete text.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, you just need to use
`(add-hook post-self-insert-hook #'function)`, it executes `function` after each keypress.

Comment: This will only work for keys that are bound to `self-insert-command` (generally alphanumeric keys and punctuation in text and programming major modes).  You can get a list of all recent keypresses with `C-h l` or `M-x view-lossage`, and in the help for that it notes that `open-dribble-file` records all keypresses.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at `post-command-hook`.